DX12 Depth buffer not drawning
I trying to render a simple quad with DX12 but i'm having some trouble.
Testing in render dock looks like the Depth buffer is blank.
The mesh looks well in render doc.
Here is my depht configs
 D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC DSVHeapDesc = {};
 DSVHeapDesc.NumDescriptors = 1;
 DSVHeapDesc.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_DSV;
 DSVHeapDesc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE;
 DSVHeapDesc.NodeMask = 0;
 HRESULT hr = mDevice->CreateDescriptorHeap(&DSVHeapDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&mDSVHeap));
 if (FAILED(hr))
 {
     PopError(hr, L"Error on CreateDescriptorHeap DSV");
 }


 //Create Depht/Stencil buffer and view
 DXGI_FORMAT mDephtStencilFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;

 D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC depthStencilDesc = {};
 depthStencilDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
 depthStencilDesc.Alignment = 0;
 depthStencilDesc.Width = mWidth;
 depthStencilDesc.Height = mHeight;
 depthStencilDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
 depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
 depthStencilDesc.Format = mDephtStencilFormat;
 depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
 depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
 depthStencilDesc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNKNOWN;
 depthStencilDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_DEPTH_STENCIL;

 D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE optClear;
 optClear.Format = mDephtStencilFormat;
 optClear.DepthStencil.Depth = 1.0f;
 optClear.DepthStencil.Stencil = NULL;

 D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapProperties = {};
 heapProperties.Type = D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT;
 heapProperties.CPUPageProperty = D3D12_CPU_PAGE_PROPERTY_UNKNOWN;
 heapProperties.MemoryPoolPreference = D3D12_MEMORY_POOL_UNKNOWN;
 heapProperties.CreationNodeMask = NULL;
 heapProperties.VisibleNodeMask = NULL;
 ID3D12Resource* mDepthStencilBuffer;
 hr = mDevice->CreateCommittedResource(&heapProperties, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &depthStencilDesc,
     D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_DEPTH_WRITE, &optClear, IID_PPV_ARGS(&mDepthStencilBuffer));
 if (FAILED(hr))
 {
     PopError(hr, L"Error on CreateCommittedResource Depth/Stencil");
 }

 D3D12_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsvDesc = {};
 dsvDesc.Format = mDephtStencilFormat;
 dsvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
 dsvDesc.Flags = D3D12_DSV_FLAG_NONE;
 dsvDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
 D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE heapHandleDsv = mDSVHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
 mDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilBuffer, &dsvDesc, heapHandleDsv);

I'm setting the render targets like so:
D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandler = mRTVHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE dsvHandler = mDSVHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
mCommandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtvHandler, FALSE, &dsvHandler);

Clearing the dsv:
D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE dsvHandler = mDSVHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
mCommandList->ClearDepthStencilView(dsvHandler, D3D12_CLEAR_FLAG_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0, 0, nullptr);

Setting up Pipiline state:
D3D12_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterizerDesc = {};
rasterizerDesc.FillMode = D3D12_FILL_MODE_SOLID;
rasterizerDesc.CullMode = D3D12_CULL_MODE_NONE;
rasterizerDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
rasterizerDesc.DepthBias = D3D12_DEFAULT_DEPTH_BIAS;
rasterizerDesc.DepthBiasClamp = D3D12_DEFAULT_DEPTH_BIAS_CLAMP;
rasterizerDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = D3D12_DEFAULT_SLOPE_SCALED_DEPTH_BIAS;
rasterizerDesc.DepthClipEnable = TRUE;
rasterizerDesc.MultisampleEnable = FALSE;
rasterizerDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = FALSE;
rasterizerDesc.ForcedSampleCount = 0;
rasterizerDesc.ConservativeRaster = D3D12_CONSERVATIVE_RASTERIZATION_MODE_OFF;

D3D12_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthDesc = {};
depthDesc.DepthEnable = TRUE;
depthDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D12_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthDesc.DepthFunc = D3D12_COMPARISON_FUNC_LESS;
depthDesc.StencilEnable = FALSE;

D3D12_BLEND_DESC blendDesc = {};
blendDesc.AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;
blendDesc.IndependentBlendEnable = FALSE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = FALSE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].LogicOpEnable = FALSE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D12_BLEND_ONE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D12_BLEND_ZERO;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D12_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D12_BLEND_ONE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D12_BLEND_ZERO;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D12_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].LogicOp = D3D12_LOGIC_OP_NOOP;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D12_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC psDesc = {};
psDesc.InputLayout = mInputLayoutDesc;
psDesc.pRootSignature = mRootSignature;
psDesc.VS = mShaderByteCodeVS;
psDesc.PS = mShaderByteCodePS;
psDesc.RasterizerState = rasterizerDesc;
psDesc.BlendState = blendDesc;
psDesc.NumRenderTargets = 1;
psDesc.RTVFormats[0] = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
psDesc.DSVFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
psDesc.DepthStencilState = depthDesc;
psDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
psDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
psDesc.PrimitiveTopologyType = D3D12_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_TRIANGLE;
HRESULT hr = mDevice->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&psDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&mPipelineState));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    PopError(hr, L"Fail to CreateGraphicsPipelineState");
}

mCommandList->SetPipelineState(mPipelineState);

I tried to change some params and review the execution order but i can't find the problem.
I don't need a matrix projection yet, i'm junts trying to render a quad for now
Here my shaders
VS
struct InVS
{
    float3 pos : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};



struct OutVS
{
    float4 pos : SV_Position;
    float4 color : COLOR;    
};

OutVS main(InVS IN)
{
    OutVS outVs;
    outVs.pos = float4(IN.pos, 1.0f);
    outVs.color = IN.color;
    return outVs;    
}

PS
struct InPS
{
    float4 pos : SV_Position;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

float4 main(InPS IN) : SV_Target
{
    return IN.color;
}


I found the solution, it was a parameter in D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC.
I just added mPsDesc.SampleMask = UINT_MAX; and works well. :)
